# Trying to auto generate the coordinates of a point using QGIS and QField

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qfield

I am using QGIS 3.10 for windows, and I am trying to create a shapefile such that I can load it into QField and take points in the field, and have those points auto generate their coordinates. I have tried using the `$x` and `$y` expressions, but they either are not working or not saving, because every time I try to create a point the Easting and Northing fields are still NULL and when I go back into the Field Calculator the expression is blank. Below are my attribute table and attributes form showing the expression:

[image: Here is my attribute table]

[image: Here is the attributes form]

Answer (score 4):

Try to insert this $x and $y expression in "Default value" field and check "Apply default value on update" box.

Comment: Thank you! I will try everything and see if anything helps

Comment: Hi I think this worked!! The coordinates are decimal degrees not in easting and northing but I think I can figure it out thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have you data in Geopackage, you can use triggers for that.

Same examples:

-- Trigger to calculate the coordinate X/Y of a newly added point geometry

CREATE TRIGGER insert_x AFTER INSERT ON points
BEGIN
UPDATE points SET x = st_x(geometry);
END;

-- Trigger to calculate the coordinate X/Y of an edited point geometry

CREATE TRIGGER update_x AFTER UPDATE OF geometry ON points
BEGIN
UPDATE points SET x = st_x(geometry);
END;

Comment: Thank you! I will try everything and see if anything helps

Answer (score -1):

Create a virtual field in your layer, use the $x expression, this will be a 'live' record of the position which will change if you later move your point.....